# SP.js "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'get_staticObjects'"

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sp.js

I am trying to write a small SPA that acts as a UI layer for a SharePoint list.

I have successfully done so with a regular AJAX call, but, due to the limitations of that method, I now want to do so with the JavaScript Object Model.

The problem I am encountering is an error with SP.js (from the title):

*Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'get_staticObjects'*

This pretty much prevents me from even getting to the script.

Here is the code for the page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>JavaScript Object Model Test</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/knockout-2.3.0.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/MicrosoftAjax.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/1033/init.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/SP.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/SP.Core.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var siteUrl = '/sites/MySiteCollection';
    function retrieveListItems() {
        var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
        var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Announcements');
        var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
        camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><Query><Where><Geq><FieldRef Name=\'ID\'/>' + 
            '<Value Type=\'Number\'>1</Value></Geq></Where></Query><RowLimit>10</RowLimit></View>');
        this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);
        clientContext.load(collListItem);
        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));       
    }

    function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {
        var listItemInfo = '';
        var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();
        while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
            var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
            listItemInfo += '\nID: ' + oListItem.get_id() + 
                '\nTitle: ' + oListItem.get_item('Title') + 
                '\nBody: ' + oListItem.get_item('Body');
        }
        alert(listItemInfo.toString());
    }
    function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
        alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
    }
    ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(retrieveListItems, "sp.js");
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I run that, nothing happens, but the console outputs the error above.

Comment: Based on John Chapman's comment (http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/22776/18140) the answer may be that what I am attempting is not possible.

I will attempt to recreate my page in a SharePoint application page.

Comment: You may want to try some third party libraries like SharepointPlus (http://aymkdn.github.io/SharepointPlus/) or SPServices (http://spservices.codeplex.com/) instead of the ones from Microsoft that are not easy to use....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this issue by creating a blank page in SharePoint Designer and embedding my HTML and linking to my scripts in that. SharePoint will not properly load the JavaScript framework in an HTML page--only in an SharePoint-created ASPX page.